# How to automatically resolve model attributes on Sails.js routes?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, restful-url, yeoman-generator

It is pretty easy to create an API using [Sails.js Generate](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-generate). Getting [this tutorial example](http://maangalabs.com/blog/2014/07/26/generating-rest-api-with-sails-js-part-2/), running

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1337/employee/1
```

returns

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email" "john@email.com",
    "empnum" "123",
    "createdAt" "2015-10-25T19:25:16.559Z",
    "updatedAt" "2015-10-25T19:25:16.559Z",
}
```

and

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1337/employee/1?fields=name
```

would return

```
{
    "name": "John Smith"
}
```

Instead of passing a fields array, how can I configure Sails.js to resolve the subresource path like:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1337/employee/1/name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom route and controller function, e.g.:

**config/routes.js:**

```
"GET /employee/:id/:field": "EmployeeController.findOneFiltered"
```

**api/controllers/EmployeeController.js**

```
findOneFiltered: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param("id");
    var field = req.param("field");

    // Fetch from database by id
    Employee.findOne(id)
    .then(function(employee) {
        // Error: employee with specified id not found
        if (!employee) {
            return res.notFound();
        }

        // Error: specified field is invalid
        if (typeof employee[field] === "undefined") {
            return res.badRequest();
        }

        // Success: return attribute name and value
        var result = {};
        result[field] = employee[field];
        return res.json(result);
    })
    // Some error occurred
    .catch(function(err) {
        return res.serverError({
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```